# Comparisons between generic types in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

Consider the following segment of code -

```
  abstract class Vehicle {
    val name: String
  }
  case class Car(name: String) extends Vehicle
  case class Truck(name: String) extends Vehicle

  abstract class VehicleContainer[T <: Vehicle] {
    def compare(that: VehicleContainer[T]): Int
  }

  class CarContainer(wheels: Int) extends VehicleContainer[Car] {
    override def compare(that: CarContainer): Int = ???
  }
```

The intention here is to have a compare method on the `VehicleContainer` that can be defined for each specific instance of `VehicleContainer`. The `compare` method comparison clause needs to be unique for each instance, because it could be comparing using attributes specific to that instance and hence not defined in the abstract base class `VehicleContainer`.

The trouble is that this does not work in it's current form, i.e. the override for `compare` is illegal. What I am not able to understand is how to accomplish this - define a base class that indicates that the sub classes need to implement a compare method, where the method argument to that `compare` method is that sub class itself. Would appreciate a pointer to the right concept here if it's some straightforward generics concept that I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you writing `override def compare(that: VehicleContainer[Car]): Int` instead?

Comment: If I do that I cannot get something like this to work - 

`override def compare(that: VehicleContainer[Car]): Int = this.wheels - that.wheels`

Comment: `def compare[K <: VehicleContainer[T]](that: K): Int` and probaby use `traits`

Comment: OK, @JaiPrabhu. I don't know what a `VehicleContainer` is, but you're obviously promising that one can be compared to another (of the same type). So you need to fulfill that promise. If that means implementing `def compare(that: VehicleContainer[Car])` only to throw an exception if `that` is not a `CarContainer`, so be it.

I feel like the real problem here is a lack of documentation of what these classes mean, without which it's not clear what the implementation needs to be.

Comment: If I continue with my logic, you should delete the `compare` method from `VehicleContainer`, since you don't plan to offer that. But then the `VehicleContainer` type itself adds nothing, so might as well delete that, too. So you're really looking for `CarContainer` to implement a trait like `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Mike!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve your problem could be use of [F-bounded polymophism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded). You would just need one additional type parameter:

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    val name: String
}

case class Car(name: String) extends Vehicle
case class Truck(name: String) extends Vehicle

abstract class VehicleContainer[T <: Vehicle, V <: VehicleContainer[T, V]] {
    def compare(that: V): Int
}

class CarContainer(wheels: Int) extends VehicleContainer[Car, CarContainer] {
    override def compare(that: CarContainer): Int = ???
}
```